# Projective cellular varieties with singular cohomology admitting torsion different from two

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Is there a simple enough example of a projective cellular variety $X$ (cellular decomposition by affine spaces) such that $H^*(X(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{Z})$ has an element with torsion different from 2? (3,4,5, for example)

Comment: Depends on the definition of simple enough, I guess.